# Magento db access configuration

Tags: php, database, magento, configuration

I am sure this is a very newb question, I am new to magento as well as PHP.
I am having difficulties connecting my megento install to connect to MySQL instance. I have installed Zend package and have tried editing config.xml and local.xml under \zend\magento\app\etc dir. as following

```
        <connection>//config.xml
            <host>localhost:4928</host>
            <username>root</username>
            <password>test</password>
            <dbname>store</dbname>
            <model>mysql4</model>
            <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
            <type>pdo_mysql</type>
            <active>0</active>
        </connection>

                <connection> //local.xml
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost:4928]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[test]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[store]]></dbname>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
```

After doing this I am getting the following errors

```
Warning: include(Mage\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Backend\Customlayoutupdate.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in E:\servers\zend\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 70
Trace:
#0 E:\servers\zend\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php(70): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage\Ca...', 'E:\servers\zend...', 70, Array)
#1 E:\servers\zend\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php(70): __autoload()
#2 [internal function]: __autoload('Mage_Catalog_Mo...')
#3 E:\servers\zend\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(967): class_exists('Mage_Catalog_Mo...')
```

I have read documentation at 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customize_part_of_configuration

Comment: Why don't you use web based installation?

Comment: @tim All i did is install the Magento MSI and this is the error message that is coming. This comes up when I try to go to localhost/Magento or localhost/Magento/install.php

Comment: @Tim After your suggestion I placed my downloader.php in the Zend server and went through online downloader, right after the "Successful download" message it navigates to a page which shows exact same error message as above!

Comment: Is your server meeting http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements ?

Comment: One of the requirements is Apache server but you say you're using Zend server.

Comment: Did you check the file permissions that they are readable and executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a real answer (yet),  but I'm not able to add a comment to you question, yet. ;)

It seems that the error doesn't have to do anything with your database connection. Pleae check, if the following file exists in your local Magento installation:

`E:\servers\zend\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Backend\Customlayoutupdate.php`

Magento cannot load the file above - maybe it's missing or the access rights are not set correct.

Which Magento version are you using?